# Z-indexes not working?

Tags: html, flash, z-index

I have a webpage at  http://www.erictan.net/slideshowpro/ and the flash slideshow is covering up the website header. (you might see the header load up before the flash loads)

I'm trying to figure out how to get the header to show above the flash. I thought z-index would correct this -  but not.

Please feel free to take a look at the source code.

Can anyone advise? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add a `wmode: "transparent"` to the param section of the `SlideShowPro` init.  There is one on the page, but it is in the wrong place.